# How do I get OBDII software working?

Tags: usb, devices, serial-port

I have an [ODBII USB cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002WIN8VQ) for vehicle diagnostics, unfortunately I haven't been able to get it working on Ubuntu 12.04. The closest I've come is using the VAG-COM software with wine, using the `ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 ~/.wine/dosdevices/com1` trick and running `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 speed 9600` repeatedly. It will connect and show the vehicle is OBDII, but none of the useful features seem to be working. I tried:

- Scantool - says it's connecting to the /dev/device in terminal, but doesn't.
- obdgpslogger - times out all the time.
- [pyobd - This](https://github.com/peterh/pyobd) seems to be the most up-to-date source I could find, I had to adjust the code a bit to work ([see here for changes](https://github.com/programmin1/pyobd)). Still, in obd_io.py interpret_result function, it says it's looking for 4 space separated numbers, where the usb-serial is receiving bogus code "0100" instead?
- [freediag](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freediag/) - I tried compiling, `sh ./configure` ran fine. I had to change some executable bit to make it start to compile, but now running `make` gives error:

  diag_general.c:52: undefined reference to `diag_l0_config'
   diag_general.c:55: undefined reference to`diag_l2_config'
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
   ...

  and fails.

The device shows up in lsusb as:

```
ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
```

Is the problem that these native tools don't expect a USB serial, or a serial of this type? Or are these apps too old to recognize OBD2 of this vehicle?

Answer (score 2):

> Reference Data 1.This cable can not work if your car uses a protocol ssystem like VPW,PWM or Can-bus

This is a direct copy/paste from the Amazon page for the cable you link to. It may be that the cable just doesn't work with your device, though I would think the programs should see a non-working cable attached.

Have you also tried [Freediag](http://freediag.org/)?

Comment: I don't know of any vehicles with CAN/VPW/etc, mine is OBDII (the cable has "OBDII" embedded into the car end). I tried Freediag, but it wouldn't compile. See updated info in question.

Comment: OK. So, OBD-II isn't a protocol, itself. There are multiple protocols which fall under the OBD-II standard. If your vehicle is a US vehicle newer than 2008, it's almost certainly using CAN. If it's older, it may or may not be using it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Board_Diagnostics#OBD-II_Signal_Protocols for some more info. What year/make/model is the vehicle you're attempting to use it with?

Comment: Good find! I didn't know there were different protocols. The diagnostics connector has 6 wires connected, three are together.

Comment: Pins 1, 6, 10, 12, 13, and 14 have wires going from the diagnostics port. This page doesn't list the protocol: http://www.auterraweb.com/obdiipinout.html Furthermore, the manual makes no mention of OBD.

Comment: Those pins are on the cable side, or in your vehicle? What year/make/model is the car?

Comment: The cable has all pins, but only 1,6,10,12,13,14 are on the diagnostic port. I looked up the model and on one forum they say it uses Nissan Consult, which is a proprietary system, not OBD :(

Comment: I think you might be reading the pins backward on the obd port on the car. Is it a pre-2000 Nissan? Does the port on the car have only 14 pins? The Nissan Consult connector is 14 pins and shaped differently than the OBD-II connector, so you shouldn't even be able to plug them together.

Comment: Pre-2000 and it has exact same connector as OBDII, but those pins don't match any specification I've found. See http://www.mp3car.com/engine-management-obd-ii-engine-diagnostics-etc/41160-pls-recommend-a-scantool-for-nissan-200sx-s14a.html

Comment: If it's actually Consult, then you'll need something like this, instead: http://www.plmsdevelopments.com/consult_if.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Try these resources:

[Using ScanTool(win) under Linux using Wine](https://www.scantool.net/forum/index.php?action=printpage;topic=3086.0)

[Ubuntu Forums: OBDII Code Readers COM1 Port](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1264807)

Comment: That windows tool, Scantool is the same program as the one in Ubuntu repository, except it doesn't even list COM ports to select!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded freediag source from https://sourceforge.net/p/freediag/gitrepo/ci/master/tree/ and
had no problems compiling it on Ubuntu 20.04 and on Fedora 31. Perhaps your missing a prerequisite. Anyways it seems to work quite well.

Comment: It would be best if you would explain *how* to apply your solution.