# Is there any good car diagnostics application?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any application with which I could do car diagnostics over OBDI, OBDII etc. ?

Comment: Did you try searching the software center? I typed 'OBD' and have four results already. (Don't mis-type and search for ODB, you don't want him working on your car anyway)

Comment: In 12.04 I see only two packages, `obdgpslogger` and `scantool`. Development of the latter was discontinued in 2009.

According to documentation, `obdgpslogger` supports OBDII over elm327-compatible devices, but I have no clue what that means in practice. Would it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Theoretically" yes. There are some [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkdRdKbMhPI)s and tutorials such as [this one](http://codeseekah.com/2012/02/22/elm327-to-rs232-in-linux/) (notice several comments noting problems of compatibility). Some have succeeded getting the right hardware to work. [I had tried this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135748/how-do-i-get-obdii-software-working) with a cheaper device from Amazon (on two... no, three? versions of Linux), with no useful response. This may be defective device, or it may be that the vehicles I try had a different protocol (it turns out OBDII is actually many different *[signal protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Board_Diagnostics#OBD-II)*, which you may be able to look up or view by pinout). It may be better to buy a dedicated device for OBD reading.